# How do I control the Nuget output for ASP.NET 5 project.json

Tags: asp.net, nuget, asp.net-core

I have a css/js framework I am building.  This may have been a mistake, but I have a test mvc application (MVC6 Asp.net5) in the same project that I am developing the css/js framework.  I would like to publish the framework via Nuget to my company repo, but I don't want to carry with it any of the source code or dll dependencies of the test application.  Is there a way to excluded these components in the Nuget package?   I see publish exclude in the project.json but I'm not sure exactly what that does and I haven't found any good documentation on project.json.

Comment: Nuget will be not used in ASP.NET 5 for **client side** components. Thus creating Nuget package with CSS/JS files will be not help for other ASP:NET projects of your company.

Comment: @Oleg - are you referring to Bower as a means of distributing client side packages?  While it is true, Bower is the preferred mechanism in ASP.NET 5, nuget still remains a viable solution.  Especially since most of the company is still utilizing ASP.NET 4 and below.  Bower is not a supported WF for these versions and as such I need to play nice.  My current dev efforts are in ASP.NET 5, but the css/js should be able to be used in older projects.

Comment: I understand all of that. I was just wounder that you asked about creating NuGet packages or CSS/JS in context of ASP.NET 5. You should decide what is really important: ASP.NET 5 or NuGet. I personally create NuGet packages with respect of [NuGet Package Explorer 3.9](https://npe.codeplex.com/). One can easy create new package of download some existing one and modify it. I publish [free-jqgrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) for example. Thus I see no problem in creating NuGet packages with CSS/JS, but one will not able to use the packages in ASP.NET 5 projects.